# Observable using switchMap type error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I'm still learning RxJS and I'm trying to setup a datatable that observes a stream of data that changes via a service, can someone take a look at my code and tell me how to get the right response from this observable?

search.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    constructor(
        private apiService: ApiService
    ) { }

    private searchSource = new BehaviorSubject<object>(this.getInitialCollections());

    public currentMessage = this.searchSource.asObservable();

    getInitialCollections(): object {
        return this.apiService.get('/cmt-api/search/merch/collections/_search');
    }

    search(phrase: string) {
        let results = this.apiService.post('/cmt-api/search/merch/collections/_search', { phrase: phrase })
            .subscribe(data => this.changeMessage(data));
    }

    changeMessage(results: object) {
        this.searchSource.next(results)
    }

    readCollectionResult(result: any): Asset[] {
        let data = JSON.parse(result._body).data;
        return data.map(asset => {
            return {
                id: asset.id,
                collectionName: asset.collectionName,
                collectionId: asset.collectionId,
                objectType: asset.objectType,
                displayType: asset.displayType,
                size: asset.size,
                createDate: asset.createDate,
                modifiedDate: asset.modifiedDate,
                publishedDate: asset.publishedDate,
                parentFolderId: asset.parentFolderId
            };
        });
    }
}
```

datatable.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mat-datatable',
    styleUrls: ['./datatable.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './datatable.component.html',
})
export class DatatableComponent {
    displayedColumns = ['id', 'collectionName', 'displayType', 'size'];
    datatableDatabase: SearchDataSet | null;
    dataSource: SearchDataSource | null;

    constructor(
        private searchService: SearchService
    ) {
        this.datatableDatabase = new SearchDataSet(searchService);
        this.dataSource = new SearchDataSource(this.datatableDatabase);
    }
}

export class SearchDataSet {
    dataChange: BehaviorSubject<Asset[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Asset[]>([]);
    get data(): object { return this.dataChange.value; }

    constructor(
        private searchService: SearchService
    ) { }

    getCollections() {
        this.searchService.currentMessage.subscribe(results => {
            this.dataChange.next(this.searchService.readCollectionResult(results))
        });
    }
}

export class SearchDataSource extends DataSource<Asset> {
    constructor(private _searchDataset: SearchDataSet) {
        super();
    }

    /** Connect function called by the table to retrieve one stream containing the data to render. */
    connect(): Observable<Asset[]> {
        return this._searchDataset.dataChange
            .switchMap(() => { <----- ERROR (see below)
                return this._searchDataset.getCollections()
            });
    }

    disconnect() { }
}
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Asset[], index: number) => ObservableInput<Asset[]>'.
```

Comment: `this._searchDataset.getCollections()` doesn't return anything. It needs to return an observable.

Answer (score 1):

try this. getCollections need to return a Observable

```
getCollections() {
    return this.searchService.currentMessage.map(results => {
       return this.searchService.readCollectionResult(results)
    }).map(value=>{
       this.dataChange.next(value) 
       return value
    });   
}
```

Comment: Or OP could use the `tap` pipe instead which allows for getting the current observable's value but does not require the value to be returned.